# alternative for IndexRoute in react-router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am following a course where the author has written some code for routing in react using `react-router` version 3.

```
<Router history={browserHistory} >
  <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}>
   </Route>
</Router>
```

While following the course(in which I am using using `router` version 4), I came to know that now the `<IndexRoute>` doesn't exists. I googled for alternative and found that `exact` is the alternative. But I don't know how to use `exact` for meeting this requirement. The author want the `Main` component always on the DOM, and based on the url only the child components should change(i.e `Single` or `PhotoGrid`).
I tried below code, which is of course the wrong one:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Main} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={PhotoGrid} />
      <Route path="/veiw/:postId" component={Single} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

My components are:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>
            <Link to="/">Reduxtagram</Link>
          </h1>
          {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
        </div>           
    );
  }
}

class PhotoGrid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="photo-grid">PhotoGrid</div>;
  }
}

class Single extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="single-photo">Single</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Switch` component will only render the first `Route` that is a match.

You could use the `Main` component as a regular component and use the `Switch` as `children` for that.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={PhotoGrid} />
      <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single} />
    </Switch>
  </Main>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I used `Switch` to avoid this error `A <Router> may have only one child element`.
And from your code, I am again facing this error. I think we need to nest all the components/routes inside `BrowserRouter ` in a single tag

Comment: With this code, the `Main` and the `PhotoGrid` are at adjacent components. The requirement is, the `PhotoGrid` should be a child of `Main`

Comment: Also, when I am changing the url to `/view/1234`, the `Single` component is not getting rendered.

Comment: @TheCoder I updated the answer. `path="/view/:postId"` will still match `/view/1234`

Comment: already tried this, this doesn't even print the `PhotoGrid` component.

Comment: Updated my question, added the components used

Comment: I was missing `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}` in `Main` component which was not adding the child components. Added to the question as well.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old question but im following the same course and i decided to update all the libraries, basically i had to restructure the app like this:

reduxtagram.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
// import css
import css from './styles/style.styl';

// import react router deps

const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>
)

render(router , document.getElementById('root'));
```

main.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import PhotoGrid from './PhotoGrid';
import Single from './Single';
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {history} from '../store';

export default class Main extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Route
                path="/"
                render={(routeProps) => (
                    <h1>
                        <Link to='/'>Reduxstagram </Link>
                    </h1>
                )}/>

                <Route
                path="/grid"
                render={(routeProps) => (
                    <PhotoGrid {...routeProps} {...this.props} />
                )}/>

                <Route
                path="/grid/view/:postID"
                render={(routeProps) => (
                    <Single {...routeProps} {...this.props} />
                )}/>

            </Router>
        </div>
    )
    }
}
```